# 2sls asssumptions vs IV assumptions

Tags: econometrics, 2sls

Silly question but I was confused about the independence assumption for instrumental variables when they are used in 2SLS. Is it the case that the instrumental variable used in 2SLS only has to be as good as randomly assigned *after controlling for other covariates?* Or does it have to be independent of outcomes without controlling for covariates?

I'm not sure my question makes sense so e.g.: In a 2SLS regression of wages on education and an area dummy, using a dummy variable indicating whether someone lives near a university as an IV for education (M); does M have to be as good as randomly assigned among all observations to satisfy independence? Or only as good as randomly assigned *conditional on the area dummy?*

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that independent of outcome with controlling for covariates is fine since the control variables will absorb any correlated variations.

Considering the example you mentioned, we are interested in the effect of wages on education. The first stage and second stages for 2SLS will be:
$$Wage= \beta_{0}Area+\beta_{n}Controls_{n}+\epsilon$$
$$Education= \beta_{0}\hat{Wage}+\beta_{n}Controls_{n}+\epsilon$$
where $\hat{Wage}$ is the estimated value for $Wage$. Two conditions (Exclusion Restriction and Relevance) that will need to be satisfied to validate the instrument will be:
$$Cov(\epsilon Area|Controls)=0\ (1)$$
$$Corr(Wage Area|Controls)\neq0\ (2)$$
Note here that both assumptions are conditions on Controls. In real practice, equation (1) could also be without the condition, which will be harder to achieve.